# vb.net code behind - using subs and functions in another code file

Tags: vb.net, code-behind

I have a vb.net project here using code behind.
Basically I have a page.aspx.vb code file with literally thousands of lines of code. I wanted to take all the subs and functions out of it to make it more "manageable" - but I have no idea how I can call subs from separate code files.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks.
DS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new project just add `.dll` files from old project as a **reference** and then you can use those subs (They have to be Public).

You can find more about references [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply... it's not a new project. it's the same project, but just a different file. so i would have a page.aspx.vb and i want it to use functions.vb

Comment: @dstewart101 in that case just make that Class Public and you could be able to use it. Also, you can try to make a new instance `OldClass = New OldClass`

Answer (score 0):

In `VB.Net`  you can use `modules` in order to make subs and functions accessible from all over your code

```
Modules in `VB.Net` are similar to `static classes` in `c#`
```